# SQL and date comparison

Tags: php, sql, date

I have a sql statement, i select a few items, but I need to make sure that the date i have saved is greater then the current date.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date > current_date
```

How do I make the code over, working?

Column date is saved like this 0000-00-00 00:00:00 (usual save, in other words).

---

This is what I try to achieve: AND time > current_date OR time == NULL But it ain't working. The time column is currently 0000-00-00 00:00:00 which is NULL, right?

Or how can I do, it must be greater than or equal to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: What you show above should work. Does it not? If not, can you show some example values that don't work?

Comment: If you're looking for current date time in SQL, that depends on the database you're using (mysql / sqlserver / oracle / ...)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date > NOW() or column_date IS null`

Comment: Hi, NULL is nothing and '0000-00-00 00:00:00' isn't null :) At this moment you have try with this: time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL, `NOW()` should do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date > NOW()
```

If you want to eliminate the time value and just compare to date value, following could be used:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date > CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Mysql Function `NOW()`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date > NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this documentation article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html), `0000-00-00` is a "dummy date" that can be used *instead of* NULL, which means `0000-00-00` itself is *not* NULL.

Given that `0000-00-00` cannot be greater than any other date, you should use either a condition with `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date > NOW() OR column_date = '0000-00-00'
```

or a union:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date > NOW()
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_date = '0000-00-00'
```

Alternatively you could use a construct like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE IFNULL(NULLIF(column_name, '0000-00-00'), '9999-12-31') > NOW()
```

But that would probably prohibit the query from taking advantage of the index on `column_date`, if any.